# Java - Marked/Unmarked Objects in Concurrent Mark Sweep GC

Tags: java, oracle, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

I was going through [this link from oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html#t1s3) and just trying to understand/confirm some points.

1) For CMS phases - If an object is marked as "Reachable" it also means that the object is live? Or "Live" and "Reachable" aren't "One and the Same" ?

2) If something is not marked as "Reachable" that is by default, Unreachable  ? Or the simple principle "If I haven't marked you as `Reachable`, you are unreachable" ?

2) Even though it doesn't explicitly mention, I am assuming that after a certain threshold (may be some time stamp or some counter) is met, all old generation (NOT marked as "Reachable") objects are cleaned?

I must say that the link is quite nice but I guess I am one of those readers who looks for explicitly "Yes/No" statements. So if anyone can confirm with a simple yes/no to those questions above it will do :).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If an object is not marked. It's "Unreachable"

"Unreachable" objects are not dead yet. It still lives in memory. But it's useless since no objects has reference to it. `Dead` in this context means "Kicked out of the old generation space".

With CMS GC, you have to set a old generation usage threshold with JVM option, It has it's default value. After memory usage reached threshold it starts to sweep out "Unreachable" objects (now it is released from memory)

Comment: "Unreachable objects are not dead yet" - I am not sure that's correct because on that link it says "Unmarked objects == Dead Objects"

Comment: @ha9u63ar "Dead" has many meanings I Think. My word "Dead" means that get rid out from memory. Document's "Dead" is more bigger meaning than my Dead

Comment: @ha9u63ar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html  according to this document default threshold is appox. 92%

Answer (score 0):

The *general* formal definition of what is colloquially called “live”, “not garbage” or “dead”, “garbage” considers only *reachability*.

Compare with [The Java® Language Specification, §12.6.1. Implementing Finalization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1):

> Every object can be characterized by two attributes: it may be *reachable*, *finalizer-reachable*, or *unreachable*, and it may also be *unfinalized*, *finalizable*, or *finalized*.
>
> A *reachable* object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.
>
> A *finalizer-reachable* object can be reached from some finalizable object through some chain of references, but not from any live thread.
>
> An *unreachable* object cannot be reached by either means.
>
> An *unfinalized* object has never had its finalizer automatically invoked.
>
> A *finalized* object has had its finalizer automatically invoked.
>
> A *finalizable* object has never had its finalizer automatically invoked, but the Java Virtual Machine may eventually automatically invoke its finalizer.

So *yes*¹, *reachable* means “live” and *unreachable* means “dead” or “garbage” and *yes*¹, not being *reachable* implies being *unreachable* and marking the *reachable* objects is the most straight-forward way to test unreachability.

---

¹ just because you said you like the answer in terms of “yes” or “no”

---

The 3rd point can’t be answered with “yes” or “no”, as there is no such thing as “cleaning”.

*unfinalized* objects are referenced by a special list. If these objects are only reachable through this special reference, they get enqueued for finalization which turn them *finalizable*. These object are not *unreachable* yet.

Note that the JVM optimizes this step as the majority of all object doesn’t actually need finalization. If a class inherits the `finalize()` method from `java.lang.Object` or has an empty `finalize()` method, it is considered a “trivial finalizer” and instances of this class are not added to the list of *unfinalized* objects in the first place. This also applies to `finalize()` methods consisting of a sole `super.finalize()` call to another trivial finalizer.

So *unreachable* objects are objects whose finalizer has been executed already or having a “trivial finalizer”. In either case, no action is needed to “clean” them. These objects are not like garbage on the street that has to be picked up and put into the bin. The memory location still contains what it contained when the object was alive, but it’s unused. In fact, it was already unused before the garbage collector detected it.

The key point to end an objects life cycle is to make the memory available to new allocations. The *sweeping* of the CMS implies going through the memory and add the addresses of unreachable objects to a list of free memory. This phase starts directly after the marking, but as the C in CMS suggests, *concurrently*.

An alternative is *compacting* where other still reachable objects are moved to the location of unreachable objects. And *copying* will move (aka copy) *all* reachable objects to a new memory region, making the entire source region available to new allocations.

Common to all alternatives is that they are not doing anything with the garbage to “clean” it. Even when being part of the free memory, their memory will still contain whatever it had before, until being actually occupied and hence overwritten by another object.